# How to show input field error message in rails input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

Error message not showing only field highlighted

```
 <%= f.text_field :website,:required=>true,:pattern=>'https?://.+' %>
```

How I show that?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 (recommended): use `simple_form` gem. It makes it easy to display error messages next to the fields.
After installing the gem, you can then simply do this:

```
<%= f.input :website %>
```

Option 2: code it yourself. Something like the following would be a start. You'll probably want to add some CSS classes for styling, and decide what to do if multiple errors are present on the field.

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :website %>
  <%= @model.errors.full_messages_for(:website).join(', ') if @model.errors.has_key?(:website) %>
<% end %>
```

### Side note

The above won't work if `@model` does not have validation errors associated with the `website` field. This is typically not a concern with Rails built-in validations. I.e., if you do something like `validates_presence_of :website` - you're good. But if you have custom validations, make sure to add the errors on the `website` field when calling `errors.add`, like:

```
def some_custom_validator
  errors.add(:website, 'Something is wrong') if some_logic
end
```

If your Rails or custom validations add errors on `:base` instead (`errors.add(:base, 'some global issue')`, you may also want to have some global errors displayed at the top as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views).